# What exactly is "Install RELEASE"? How to get rid of it?

Tags: 20.04, uninstall, installed-programs

Beginner. Recently set up win10/ubuntu dual boot.

"Install RELEASE" was in my dock post-installation (Ubuntu 20.04.1). Internet search resulted in me simply removing it from favorites, however it's still listed under 'Applications'.

I've tried figuring out package name/file locations to no avail.
Nothing happens when attempting to launch the application.

I believe this should not be on my system as it seems to be related to the process of installing from USB? How do I get rid of it?

(Not sure what to tag this as, hope they're fine, sorry!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the icon open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> and type the following

```
sudo apt-get remove ubiquity
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: Thanks for accepting this as the solution. You might also consider [upvoting](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) as well.

Comment: I just created this account earlier, my upvotes don't change the publicly displayed score apparently :p