# Why does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install continue to fail with 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' error?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi

**Goal**: I am trying to install Ubuntu onto a [Dell XPS 8900](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_xps_desktop/xps-8900-desktop_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf).

**Problem**: I can't get through an Ubuntu install without the install interrupting with `Unable to install Grub in /dev/sda`, `Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda failed.' This is a fatal error.`.

**Installer**: I am using a flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Installer on it. I have tried with a flash drive that I have installed with before and I have tried with a fresh install on another flash drive that I created with the Startup Disk Creator application. [Note: I have added nomodeset and acpi=off in my grub command to start the Ubuntu Installer OS.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312786/ubuntu-18-lts-20-lts-freeze-on-boot-from-usb)

**Attempts to solve**:

- I tried to complete the grub-install myself using some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow) on askubuntu. I did the aforementioned *fix* by exiting the installer prompt (after it failed) and running the commands in the terminal. I was able to successfully complete the grub-install here. However, as the original error happens part way into an install the resulting Ubuntu OS had multiple problems. I had services that would fail or just not start (including but not limited to: networkd-dispatcher.service, NetworkManager.service, fwupd-refresh.service, apparmor.service, caspermd5.services(?) ) and I had left over remnants from the install (for example, an [application named Install RELEASE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285304/what-exactly-is-install-release-how-to-get-rid-of-it) was still in my applications).

  - Note: `chroot`ing into `/mnt` and running `grub-install /dev/sda` results in `unable to allocate pty: No such device`
- [Top answer here suggests clicking Try Ubuntu and the using the Install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS application, which didn't work for me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u)
- [Top answer here suggests that grub-install is installing to the wrong device, which isn't true for me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub)
- I am desperate now, so I updated the BIOS to its most recent update. That didn't do anything.
- I tried running grub-install prior to running the Try Install application.

  - Note: running `sudo grub-install --root-directory /mnt /dev/sda` results in `grub-instal: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Operation not permitted.`
  - Also, I worry that even if I could successfully run grub-install prior to running the Ubuntu Installer, that the Ubuntu Installer would still fail because the Ubuntu Installer might run grub-install without options.

**Question**: Why does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install continue to fail with 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' error?

**Output from `sudo fdisk -l`**:

```
<multiple /dev/loopN>
....
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, ......
Device       Size    Type
/dev/sda1    512M    EFI System
/dev/sda2    1.8T    Linux Filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.45 GiB, ......
Device      Size    Type
/dev/sdb1   3.6G    Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2   4.1M    EFI System
/dev/sdb3   300K    Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4   10.9G   Linux Filesystem
....
<multiple /dev/loop<N>>
```

**Output from `lsblk`**:

```
NAME  TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
<multiple loop<N>>
...
sda   disk
sda1  part
sda2  part
sdb   disk   /cdrom
sdb1  part
sdb2  part
sdb3  part
sdb4  part   /var/crash
             /var/log
sdc   disk
sdd   disk
sde   disk
sdf   disk
sr0   rom
```

**Output of `grub-install --version`**:

```
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7
```

**Output of `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`**:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

**Output of `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` then `p`**:

```
Number  Size   Code   Name
  1    512MiB  EF00   EFI System Partition
  2    1.8TiB  8300
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139512/discussion-on-question-by-mrdrago9-why-does-ubuntu-22-04-lts-install-continue-to).

Comment: Thanks @andrew.46. I would have done it, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Hi , I have this problem too, what did you do at the end?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Ubuntu is not able to read the HDD after installation.  I believe it is an issue with the tool used to create the partitions.  I was able to install after I installed a different Linux based OS (Prime OS). Then I was able to erase Prime and install Ubunto.  This is an issue with the installer.  It should not be this difficult to install the OS.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 live works

Answer (score 0):

sequence to try:

1. reboot again with the Ubuntu 22.04 live USB stick
2. run `lsblk` to get the partitions list = the biggest one will be the root partition and the first one would be the EFI one
3. click on drive icon to have it mounted on the default /media/ubuntu/<> or mount it manually into /<>
4. mount EFI partition into /mnt
5. run following command:

`sudo grub-install --recheck --efi-directory=/mnt --root-directory=/media/ubuntu/<<UUID>> --force --modules=part_gpt`

Comment: There appears a typo in the suggested command in the 5.) point: it probably should read `grub-install` instead of `grup-install`.