# Why does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install continue to fail with 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' error message?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation, uefi

**Goal**: I am trying to install Ubuntu onto a [Dell XPS 8900](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_xps_desktop/xps-8900-desktop_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf).

**Problem**: I can't get through an Ubuntu install without the install interrupting with `Unable to install Grub in /dev/sda`, `Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda failed.' This is a fatal error.`. Moreover `boot-repair` doesn't fix the issue.

**Installer**: I am using a flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Installer on it. I have tried with a flash drive that I have installed with before and I have tried with a fresh install on another flash drive that I created with the Startup Disk Creator application. [Note: I have added nomodeset and acpi=off in my grub command to start the Ubuntu Installer OS.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312786/ubuntu-18-lts-20-lts-freeze-on-boot-from-usb)

**Attempts to solve**:

- I tried to complete the grub-install myself using some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow) on askubuntu. I did the aforementioned *fix* by exiting the installer prompt (after it failed) and running the commands in the terminal. I was able to successfully complete the grub-install here. However, as the original error happens part way into an install the resulting Ubuntu OS had multiple problems. I had services that would fail or just not start (including but not limited to: networkd-dispatcher.service, NetworkManager.service, fwupd-refresh.service, apparmor.service, caspermd5.services(?) ) and I had left over remnants from the install (for example, an [application named Install RELEASE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285304/what-exactly-is-install-release-how-to-get-rid-of-it) was still in my applications).

  - Note: `chroot`ing into `/mnt` and running `grub-install /dev/sda` results in `unable to allocate pty: No such device`
- [Top answer here suggests clicking Try Ubuntu and the using the Install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS application, which didn't work for me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u)
- [Top answer here suggests that grub-install is installing to the wrong device, which isn't true for me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub)
- I am desperate now, so I updated the BIOS to its most recent update. That didn't do anything.
- I tried running grub-install prior to running the Try Install application.

  - Note: running `sudo grub-install --root-directory /mnt /dev/sda` results in `grub-instal: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Operation not permitted.`
  - Also, I worry that even if I could successfully run grub-install prior to running the Ubuntu Installer, that the Ubuntu Installer would still fail because the Ubuntu Installer might run grub-install without options.

**Still to Attempt**:

- `boot-repair` said that the NVram was locked. I saw [a suggestion to clear the NVRAM](https://forum.zorin.com/t/error-nvram-is-locked/17150) by [resetting the CMOS](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/xps-8900-desktop/xps-8900-desktop/procedure?guid=guid-e7cb0968-2c3c-4970-8a47-b70b169f3f35&lang=en-us). I am saving this as a last resort because I don't want to mess with the motherboard.

**Question**: Why does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install continue to fail with 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' error?

**Result of `boot-repair`**: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Shc4V4xB9T

Comment: Are you booting with any custom GRUB parameters such as "acpi=off"? This may be a similar topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439291/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-nvme1n1-grub-install-failed